# Limit with épsilon and delta , multivalues

Tags: calculus, limits

Hi i need help with about the how to apply the definition of limit correctly, the following problem

$ \lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (5,6)}x^{2}+6y^{2}-7$

I appreciate your sugerences.

Comment: What do you understand about the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits ?

Comment: not quite understand how to apply it, I would get a fairly clear outline with which lead me to demonstrate a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

The statement
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(5,6)}x^{2}+6y^{2}-7 = L$$
is defined as:

> For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$|(x^{2}+6y^{2}-7)-L|<\epsilon$$ whenever $|(x,y)-(5,6)| < \delta$.

Here we use the Euclidean norm for the dependent values:
$$|(x,y)-(5,6)| = \sqrt{(x-5)^{2}+(y-6)^{2}}.$$